# Trying to populate a JavaScript array with ActiveRecord data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm using a chart to display the top most common operating systems (e.g. XP, server 2003, etc.) and I'm trying to pull this information from ActiveRecord. I have a `Node` model that has the `operating_system` column.

From my `show` page, this is what I have at the bottom:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#nodes-os-chart',
    title: {
        text: 'Top 5 Operating Systems Detected'
    },
    data: {
        columns: [
        ['Microsoft Windows XP', 10],
        ['Microsoft Windows Server 2003', 5],
        ['Microsoft Windows Server 2016', 15]
        ],
        type : 'pie',
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
        onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
    },
    legend: {
        position: "right"
    }
});
```

However, I would like to fill in the columns array with some data from ActiveRecord, so I tried turning it into an ajax call, such as this:

```
var operating_systems = $.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname + "/node_os",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json', // added data type
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        alert(res);
    }
});
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#nodes-os-chart',
    title: {
        text: 'Top 5 Operating Systems'
    },
    data: {
        columns: operating_systems,
        type : 'pie',
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
        onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
    },
    legend: {
        position: "right"
    }
});
```

I added a route for `get 'node_os'` to map back to the necessary controller. However, now in the controller, this is the method I have defined for `node_os`:

```
  # GET /logs/4/node_os
  def node_os
    return ['Test1','Test2']
  end
```

Test1 and Test2 are just samples, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I get a pop up that says "Undefined" when I try to run this in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using this: https://medium.com/@ryannovas/pass-a-nested-array-from-rails-to-js-41f021eef459.

Basically my `show.html.erb` just makes the AJAX call and the rest happens in the `js.erb` file.